# Altair '4.1.0' returning an empty chart

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to add a symbol in my Altair chart so the user could know by color what each line represents in the chart, but when I plot it I receive an empty chart without the data I'm passing.

Meanwhile I was debugging the code and I suppose the problem is located on the line `color = alt.Color...`

```py
base = alt.Chart(new_df, title="Mean Control Chart").properties(width=600,height=500)

domain = ['Mean','LSC','LM','LIC','1 x S(+)','2 x S(+)','1 x S(-)','2 x S(-)']
range_ = ['black','red','green','red','blue','blue','blue','blue']

# Linha da media
media_chart = base.mark_line(point=True).encode(
    alt.X('amostra',type='quantitative', title='Samples', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(x_range_min_1,x_range_max_1))),
    alt.Y('media', type='quantitative', title='Mean', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(y_range_min_1,y_range_max_1))),
    color = alt.Color('Symbol',type='nominal', scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain, range=range_))
)
```

[image: Image of the dataset I'm using]

[image: Empty chart I get]

Dataset

Comment: Could you please post a sample of `new_df` as text so that others can try to reproduce your issue and figure out what is wrong? It looks like you have reshaped it compared to the screen shot you are showing

Comment: Or, if that is indeed how the dataframe looks, then you cannot use "symbol" because it is not a column in your dataframe. You would need to reshape/melt the df first to create this column, e.g. with `new_df.melt(id_vars=['amostra', 'media'], var_name='Symbol']` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Comment: @joelostblom unfortunely i can't share this df, the picture its how the dataframe looks like. I gonna do what you said and in case goes wrong, i come back.

Comment: @joelostblom i did this. Create another variable to located the changes `second_df = pd.melt(new_df, id_vars['media','LSC','LM','LIC','1 x S(+)','2 x S(+)','1 x S(-)','2 x S(-)'], var_name='Symbol')` but didn't worked. Returned this dataframe to me https://imgur.com/nIpXTx8

Comment: The `id_vars` should only be the variables you wish to keep unchanged as in my previous comment. All the rest should be collected under the new column name 'symbol'. Try the code I put above (maybe with some small tweak). You can also read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html?highlight=melt if you want to learn more about how melt works in general

Comment: @joelostblom i got it. But when i pass this line `new_df.melt(id_vars=['amostra', 'media'], var_name='Symbol')` like you said, i get this dataframe https://imgur.com/CGfALyS and this chart https://imgur.com/zlAG3Ek but he doesnt have the color from the **media** column as pass at **domain**

Comment: @joelostblom i did like this https://gist.github.com/feliperoque/9871b5850f1884fdcc57941b4b7701e0 but i'm trying to adjust the mark-point color at line chart but i get a error

Comment: It looks to me that you have now been able to plot your data frame and the chart is no longer empty, so I would consider this part solved. For why the color is not what you think, try plotting without the domain first to see what happens. If it is still not working you can ask a new question and link here.  I suggest that you try to use the domain with one of the example on the gallery page to see how it works and to be able to post a reproducible example here if needed https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/index.html. I posted an answer, so please accept that so that this is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use "Symbol" as the chart color because it is not a column in your dataframe. You would need to reshape/melt the df first to create this column, e.g. with `new_df.melt(id_vars=['amostra', 'media'], var_name='Symbol']` as per [the pandas docs on reshaping](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html?highlight=melt).